# Import CSS file dynamically depending on variable in Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have a Svelte 4.2 app with `App.svelte` as the main component. It has to load several CSS stylesheet files:

- one main one: `app.css` which is loaded anyway
- ...and one secondary one which adds some style to all the components of the app, depending on a variable. This secondary stylesheet defines many supplementary styles rules on many DOM elements of the app.

So what I did to load it dynamically is the following in `App.svelte`:

```html
<script>
  import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent.svelte";
  // ...
  let skin = window.localStorage.getItem("skin");
  import(`./style/${skin}/style_${skin}.css`);
  // ...
</script>
<main>
  <!-- ... -->
  <MyComponent />
  <!-- ... -->
</main>
```

This works great, exactly how I need it, except that I get a deprecation warning:

`Default import of CSS without "?inline" is deprecated. Add the "{ query: '?inline' }" glob option to fix this. For example: "import.meta.glob("./style/*/style_*.css", { "query": "?inline" })"`.

I couldn't figure how to fix that. I would rather not refactor the app to have to add dynamically CSS classes to many of my elements in components, I would prefer keeping as it is and rely on CSS style priority rules.

Any idea on how to fix this warning?